# Api of facebook is blinking when getting user information

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Currently make the connection to the facebook api with php, create a project in facebook developers, generate the corresponding keys and as for the permissions of users I'm using the default and the permission of the mail, allows me to enter and give permission to the application but sometimes does not bring all the user information and some times when you click the button facebook does not open the popup to log in with facebook or give permission to the application with my account, sometimes if not, I do not know why and the case is still very intermittent, in the browser console does not tell me that is due to the intermittence, something important to mention is that the day if there is a high flow of people trying to use the login with facebook but the intermittent can not be logged in, I have this script in html before the body:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
FB.init({
    appId: '<?php echo $UrlApiFacebook; ?>',
    cookie: true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml: true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
    version: 'v7.0'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
  });
};

(function(d, s, id) {                      // Load the SDK asynchronously
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
    statusChangeCallback(response, 1);        // Returns the login status.
  });
}
```

For this code I rely directly on the official documentation of facebook developer, in another javascript file is the function 'statusChangeCallback()' this file is like this:

```
function statusChangeCallback(response, i) {
  console.log('statusChangeCallback');
  console.log(response);
  if (i == 3) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {   // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
      FB.logout(function (response) {
        window.location.href = "login_out.php";
      });
    } else {
      window.location.href = "login_out.php";
    }
  } else {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {   // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else {                                 // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
      console.log("No logueado");
      FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected')
          testAPI();
      });
    }
  }
}

function testAPI() {                      // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api('/me', { fields : 'name,picture,first_name,last_name,email' }, function (response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
    onSendDataFacebook(response);
  });
}

function logoutUserFacebook() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
    statusChangeCallback(response, 3);        // Returns the login status.
  });
}

function onSendDataFacebook(userFacebook) {
  let email = "";
  let name = "";
  let last_name = "";

  var user = {
    id: userFacebook.id, nombre: userFacebook.name,
    email: userFacebook.email,
    nombrecompleto: userFacebook.first_name + ' ' + userFacebook.last_name,
    llamado: redir,
    veces: x
  }

  if(!userFacebook.email){
    user.email = email;
  }
  if(!userFacebook.name){
    user.name = name;
  }
  if(!userFacebook.first_name || !userFacebook.last_name){
    user.first_name = name;
    user.last_name = last_name;
  }

  redireclogin(user);
}
```

I would very much appreciate the help of anyone who knows what this intermission is about, thank you in advance.

Comment: write english please

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not in english

Comment: Not sure what exactly the problem is supposed to be here, what exactly is not working? That the user is not presented with the login dialog _again_, if they already granted all the requested permissions, is _normal_ - in that case, the login dialog popup will open, and automatically close right after again.